# Почему я не могу получить данные из AD?

Tags: c#

Всем Привет!

Ситуация очень странная, вот пример кода который работает:

```
            string UserName = "dalcaev";
            var f = cAD.GetUser("dalcaev");
            MessageBox.Show(f.Name);
```

Ну почему не работает так?

```
    string UserName = loginArr[0];
    var f = cAD.GetUser(UserName);
    MessageBox.Show(f.Name);
```

В `loginArr[0]` точно передаю туда "dalcaev", но в итоге получаю ошибку, можно посмотреть на скриншоте. Что не так? 
Спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал проверку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `В loginArr[0] точно передаю туда "user"` - а судя по окну `Watch`, там `"dalcaev"`.

Comment: @soon Назвал условно юзером

Comment: @shatoidil условно - сравните две строки. напишите в коде `bool smsth =  UserName == "user"`, где "user" - строка из рабочего варианта.  и посмотрите на результат.

Comment: @PashaPash false выдает

Comment: @shatoidil, проблема в том, что сейчас вопрос содержит два куска кода. Вы утверждаете, что первый вариант работает, а второй - нет. Добавив `Я условно назвал "user"`, Вы только запутали отвечающих, поскольку теперь код в вопросе явно расходится с кодом на Вашей локальной машине. Пожалуйста, исправьте код и скриншот, чтобы они действительно отражали рабочую и нерабочую версии.

Comment: @soon Все исправил, я сделал еще проверку. Картинка ниже.

Comment: @soon Спасибо! За помощь. Оказывается буква с была напечатана в массиве на русском языке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извиняюсь! Оказывается буква С в слове dalcaev была написана на русском языке!

Вот почему возникала эта ошибка!